# Country selection in android using API

Tags: java, android, rest

I need spinner item should be flag image which is from service but it is showing country name in spinner item or i can use custom list view instead of spinner which one is easy.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<String> worldlist;
    ArrayList<WorldPopulation> world;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Download JSON file AsyncTask
    new DownloadJSON().execute();

}

// Download JSON file AsyncTask
private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
        world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner 
        worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        // JSON file URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt");

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

                worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("rank"));
                worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("country"));
                worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("population"));
                worldpop.setFlag(jsonobject.optString("flag"));
                world.add(worldpop);

                // Populate spinner with country names
                worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("country"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                        TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
                        TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
                        TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);

                        // Set the text followed by the position 
                        txtrank.setText("Rank : "
                                + world.get(position).getRank());
                        txtcountry.setText("Country : "
                                + world.get(position).getCountry());
                        txtpopulation.setText("Population : "
                                + world.get(position).getPopulation());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }
}
}
```

JSONfunctions.java

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    // Convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/my_spinner" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rank" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/population"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/country" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you have set country name in your spinner how will it show flag image??

Comment: plz send me d changes to display country image instead of country name

Comment: here is nice tutorial explaining how to show image in Spinner:
http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-Spinner-customized-to-show-image-and-text.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog to open that list for replacing spinner:

```
void setStateListData() {
        try {
            final String[] stateList = new String[getStateArrGlobal().size()];
            for (int i = 0; i <getStateArrGlobal().size(); i++) {
                stateList[i] =getStateArrGlobal().get(i).getName();
            }
            showAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Select state", stateList, onClickedStateListner);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickedStateListner = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            districtArrGlobal = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
            editDistrict.setText("");
            editState.setText("" + getStateArrGlobal().get(item).getName());
            setDistrictListData(getStateArrGlobal().get(item).getId());
        }
    };
```

and use the dialog as:

```
 public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String message, String[] arrayList, DialogInterface.OnClickListener onClickedListener) {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialogBuilder.setTitle(message);
        dialogBuilder.setItems(arrayList, onClickedListener);
        //Create alert dialog object via builder
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
        //Show the dialog
        alertDialogObject.show();
    }
```

Comment: hey hi @shweta porwal can u plz say wher i have to replace it in my code

Comment: onPost execution where your spinner is placed. set there a textView and on TextView's click listner u can go with setStateListData method

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete which is better. Please check the image you can use the default interface provided by Google

[image]